# Securing CXF rest services with Shiro on Apache Karaf

Tags: java, cxf, apache-karaf, shiro

I'm trying to secure Apache CXF based rest services (Apache CXF 3.3.5) with Apache Shiro Basic Authentication (Apache Shiro 1.5.0)
in Apache Karaf 4.2.8. However I end up getting a warning message in the karaf log file like:

```
ServletController | 394 - org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http - 3.3.5 | Can't find the request for http://localhost:8181/myweb/rest-api/user's Observer
```

No other exceptions elsewhere or during WAB installation. The WAB looks fine in the webconsole with status active, however that service endpoint is not working at all producing just the the aforementioned
log entry.

I'm trying to create a new HttpContext with this WAB in order to make sure that Apache Shiro's basic authentication does not interfere with the
one of Apache Karaf Webconsole (as suggested here : http://karaf.922171.n3.nabble.com/Apache-Shiro-in-Karaf-td4048566.html). I also do not want to use the standard CXF context provided by the CXF feature in Karaf.

My web.xml:

```
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/beans.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>config-location</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

My beans.xml :

```
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- scans and register beans using annotation-config (metadata) -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.adams.karaf.service" />

    <!-- to support Java-to-JSON and vice-versa conversion -->
    <bean id="jsonProvider" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider" />

    <!-- to support Java-to-XML and vice-versa conversion -->
    <bean id="jaxbXmlProvider" class="org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory" />


    <bean id="userRestServiceImplClass" class="org.adams.karaf.service.impl.UserRestServiceImpl" />

    <jaxrs:server id="restservice" address="/rest-api">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="userRestServiceImplClass" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" /> 
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />         
        </jaxrs:extensionMappings>

        <jaxrs:providers>
            <ref bean="jsonProvider" />
            <ref bean="jaxbXmlProvider" />
        </jaxrs:providers>
    </jaxrs:server>
```

My questions now are:

- How can I create a new CXF rest service in Karaf under a new HttpContext(WebContext) to avoid interference with
  Apache Karaf's webconsole?
- Is there something missing in my configurations?
- Is the log message telling someone somthing?

You can also have a look at https://github.com/Thomas-Adams/cxf-rest-service for the complete project.

Comment: Why do you say that the cxf rest services have interference with the web console? By installing the cxf feature, you will have two separate applications (run on the same port), segregated by path

Comment: I was referring to a blog entry, where such a situation was mentioned, see here http://karaf.922171.n3.nabble.com/Apache-Shiro-in-Karaf-td4048566.html